# new columns in mysql not working dispite using same formula as previous

Tags: php, mysql

I have a system that I partly set up and partly had built, I am self taught so apologies if this query is simple.

Part of the registration form people fill in requires them to select areas of the country. i.e north, south, south west. I wanted to add a couple of options to this so followed the rules of the previous inputs in MySQL.

```
type varchar, length 255, default Null, collation latin1_swedish_ci and Null ticked.
```

For some reason on the new columns this displays the word NULL where as the others that are also empty do not?

I've also copied the previous rules on my process php page literally copying and pasting the data but with the new names and mysql fields which should transmit the data from the form to create a profile. but when I fill in the form and select the newly added areas my error message displays.....i'm assuming it must have something to do with the mysql columns i have set up?

Comment: Can you show us the table creation code, the markup for your form, etc. Without that the question will be nearly impossible to answer.

Comment: *Sam left out  a comma* :p

Comment: *Didn't you Sam?* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: please let me know if adding any parts of my code will help figure out the issue

Comment: just saw your answer, yes sure will do now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hard to follow your purpose since you didn't list the errors, but there are two different 'empty' types in MySql. You could have a TEXT (VARCHAR or whatever) column that is empty and contains the text "" (an empty string), but there is also another type of empty called NULL which represents a black hole. If you specify a column 'NOT NULL' then it will never be null, but otherwise, it can hold the null value.
In your case, the new column may be holding NULL because you never set it with the under/update query, and this may be causing issues with your select queries because NULL has no string representation (eg, you can't get the value as a string on a null value, you must explicitly check if it is null).
It sounds like you dont want your column to be null at all, requiring it to be set at all times.

Comment: the under/update query sounds like something that I could be missing this is part of the registration form                                                                             <td colspan="7">Please select all areas you will be interested in working:</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7" id="checkpanel">
      <input type="checkbox" name="london" value="london" id="forlondon">
      <label for="forlondon">London</label>

Comment: The form is irrelevant, what's happening in the php file receiving the post parameters? (The form action) What are you actually sending to the DB for the problematic column? Add some echo's or debug it to check what your sending.

Comment: Also, perhaps remove the "default NULL" from the unknown code in your question. If its always going to be checked or not, then you never want it to hold null in the first place.

Comment: once submitted the process php page works like this : if(isset($_POST['london'])){
 $london = $_POST['london'];
 }else{ $london = '';   } 
 and  $sql="INSERT INTO registration (Field1, Field3,) etc                         VALUES '$london','$outerlondon',) etc does this help?

Comment: your right I don't want it to hold NULL I want it to either display the word London or be left blank, this is how my other columns have worked and so I just followed the same as those assuming it would work the same the only difference made is the field name

Comment: Your missing a quote at 'else{$london="";}'

Comment: But also, wouldnt it make sense to have the column named "London", and for it to store a 'BIT', which is either true or false? Eg, London could be 'True' or 'False'. This would make more sense, or not, depending on everything else.

Comment: I will look into that thanks for your advise appreciate it :)